# PySpark with IPython - not running startup shell.py

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark

I have Spark (1.5.1) installed. Running PySpark with the standard Python (2.7) shell works fine and loads all the Spark modules. It also prints out a significant amount of output logs as python loads.

When I changed the variable `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython`, IPython loads but no logs are printed out and the `sc` `SparkContext` variable is not defined. It looks to me like the `shell.py` startup script is not being loaded.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you start PySpark?

Comment: I just run bin/pyspark from the shell.